# Why doesn't my page scroll function work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'am working a website that has to scroll from bottom to top. So when the page load, it shows the end of the document. Its a kind of reverse scrolling.

The menu is fixed at the bottom. When I click on a link in the menu I use Jquery animate to scroll to the element I want to see. It is working but for some reson if I click on the same link or another link it will go back to the bottom like it was toggleling the animation instead of going to the position given.

Here is my code.

```js
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel").height(winHeight);
    $("body").height(winHeight*$(".panel").length);
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
    $(".panel").height($(window).innerHeight());
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".panelCon").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});











var previous_element_pos = null ;

$(document).on("click", ".menulink", function (event) {
 var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;

console.log("Previous element position :" + previous_element_pos );

    event.preventDefault(event);

  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var window_top_position = $(window).scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);





  var link_id = ($(this).attr("id"));
  var $container = $("#"+link_id+"_panel");
  var container_height = $container.outerHeight();
  var container_top_position = $container.offset().top;
  var container_bottom_position = (container_top_position + container_height);



console.log("Original position from the view :" + container_top_position);


 if ((container_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (container_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {


    console.log('in view');
    console.log("Container top pos. :" + container_top_position);


    }
     else if(container_top_position < 0 ) {

     console.log("Pos. is negative :" + $($container).offset().top*-1);

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$($container).offset().top*-1
      }, 5000);
      
    previous_element_pos = $($container).offset().top*-1
  
    }
    
     else if(container_top_position > 0 ) {
     
       console.log("Pos. is positive :" + ($($container).offset().top)*1);
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($($container).offset().top -  previous_element_pos)*1
   
      }, 5000);
      
    previous_element_pos = $($container).offset().top*1

    } 

});
```

```css
/* FOR LOADING SCREEN IMAGE*/
.mainImg{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('../images/mainImg.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
/* FOR NAVBAR BOOTSTRAP ROUDED BORDER REMOVAL*/
.navbar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

 /* FOR NAVBAR AFFIX*/
  .affix {
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
  }
  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
 /* FOR ROUTES BLOCK DISPLAY*/
  .routes-block{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width : 200px;
    height : 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
.menulink{
    font-family: arial;
}





body {
    background-color: #111318;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.panelCon{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
.panel {
    width: 100%;
        background-color: #111318;
}
.panel h1 {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ROUTESRATEx</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
 

 


  <script src="../JS/route_app.js"></script>
</head>




<body>

  <div class="panelCon"> 
    <div id="contact_panel" class="panel">
        <h1>CONTACT</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="media_panel"class="panel">
        <h1>MEDIA</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="store_panel"class="panel">
        <h1>STORE</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="routes_panel" class="panel">
        <h1>ROUTES</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="routesrate_panel" class="panel">
        <h1>INDEX</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
   <div class="container"> 
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ROUTERATES</a>
    </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a id = "routesrate" href="#">ROUTESRATE</a></li>
    <li><a id = "routes" class="menulink" data-container="main" href="#">ROUTES</a></li>
    <li><a id = "store" class="menulink" href="#">STORE</a></li>
    <li><a id = "media" class="menulink" href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
    <li><a id = "contact" class="menulink" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


  


</body>
</html>
```

When running the script you might see some alerts. They are there to give me the position that im passing to Javascript for scrolling.

Any help would be apreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Pro tip for development : 1. use `console.log` instead of `alert`. 2. Open your console. 3. Thank me later :)

Comment: I have changed it to console log but still isnt working like it should.

Comment: I think the problem is from the math for the position

Comment: Jeremy's suggestion wasn't intended as a solution to your problem. It's simply very good development advice. Alerts are a waste of your attention and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. It works for me. Cool project you have.

You can get the distance to an element using `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.
All you need is scroll an amount of pixel equal to that distance. And do not forget to update the new position. 
The following is a rework for your click event handler.

```
       var previous_element_pos = null;

       //menu click events
        $(document).on("click", ".menulink", function (event) {

        //get selected panel id
        var link_id = ($(this).attr("id"));
        var $container = link_id + "_panel";

        //get distance to the selected panel
        var scrollDistance = document.getElementById($container).getBoundingClientRect().top;

        //scroll to new position
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (scrollDistance + previous_element_pos) * -1
        }, 5000);

        //update previous position
        previous_element_pos = scrollDistance + previous_element_pos;

    });
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for your instructive comment. I am editing it.

Comment: Much better! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you AndyLe that is working and you just saved me a lot of math!

Comment: Working great on mobile to

Comment: @MadeInDreams great news! I am glad it works for you.